# How to add custom validation to an AngularJS form?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with input fields and validation setup by adding the `required` attributes and such. But for some fields I need to do some extra validation. How would I "tap in" to the validation that `FormController` controls?

Custom validation could be something like "if these 3 fields are filled in, then this field is required and needs to be formatted in a particular way".

There's a method in `FormController.$setValidity` but that doesn't look like a public API so I rather not use it. Creating a custom directive and using `NgModelController` looks like another option, but would basically require me to create a directive for each custom validation rule, which I do not want.

Actually, marking a field from the controller as invalid (while also keeping `FormController` in sync) might be the thing that I need in the simplest scenario to get the job done, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: There is a nice article on coding monster for handling custom validations in angular JS. Check [this](http://www.aleaiactaest.ch/custom-form-validation-in-angular-js/) out

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for, since it requires custom directives, but I'll accept your answer since it's a good article anyway.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, I'd love some control at the level of the FormController. For example, I want certain custom directives to flag the FormController instance as something like `formName.$warning`.

Comment: I believe that `$$` precedes no-public apis, with `$` being public. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338493/what-is-the-double-dollar-sign-used-for-in-angular

Answer (score 377, accepted):

**Edit: added information about ngMessages (>= 1.3.X) below.**

### Standard form validation messages (1.0.X and above)

Since this is one of the top results if you Google "Angular Form Validation", currently, I want to add another answer to this for anyone coming in from there.

> There's a method in FormController.$setValidity but that doesn't look like a public API so I rather not use it.

It's "public", no worries. Use it. That's what it's for. If it weren't meant to be used, the Angular devs would have privatized it in a closure.

To do custom validation, if you don't want to use Angular-UI as the other answer suggested, you can simply roll your own validation directive.

```js
app.directive('blacklist', function (){ 
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
          var blacklist = attr.blacklist.split(',');

          //For DOM -> model validation
          ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
             var valid = blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1;
             ngModel.$setValidity('blacklist', valid);
             return valid ? value : undefined;
          });

          //For model -> DOM validation
          ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
             ngModel.$setValidity('blacklist', blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1);
             return value;
          });
      }
   };
});
```

And here's some example usage:

```html
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="doSomething()">
   <input type="text" name="fruitName" ng-model="data.fruitName" blacklist="coconuts,bananas,pears" required/>
   <span ng-show="myForm.fruitName.$error.blacklist">
      The phrase "{{data.fruitName}}" is blacklisted</span>
   <span ng-show="myForm.fruitName.$error.required">required</span>
   <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Note: in 1.2.X it's probably preferrable to substitute `ng-if` for `ng-show` above**

Here is an obligatory [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/4u8FV869aD33WozdqdQ2?p=preview)

Also, I've written a few blog entries about just this subject that goes into a little more detail:

[Angular Form Validation](http://www.benlesh.com/2012/11/angular-js-form-validation.html)

[Custom Validation Directives](http://www.benlesh.com/2012/12/angular-js-custom-validation-via.html)

### Edit: using ngMessages in 1.3.X

You can now use the ngMessages module instead of ngShow to show your error messages. It will actually work with anything, it doesn't have to be an error message, but here's the basics:

1. Include `<script src="angular-messages.js"></script>`
2. Reference `ngMessages` in your module declaration:

   ```js
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);
   ```
3. Add the appropriate markup:

   ```html
   <form name="personForm">
     <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="person.email" required/>

     <div ng-messages="personForm.email.$error">
       <div ng-message="required">required</div>
       <div ng-message="email">invalid email</div>
     </div>
   </form>
   ```

In the above markup, `ng-message="personForm.email.$error"` basically specifies a context for the `ng-message` child directives. Then  `ng-message="required"` and `ng-message="email"` specify properties on that context to watch. **Most importantly, they also specify an order to check them in**. The first one it finds in the list that is "truthy" wins, and it will show that message and none of the others.

And a [plunker for the ngMessages example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ucbkRcZxaSvWSLBC5v2z?p=preview)

Comment: If you return value on the function that you pass to $parsers.unshift, erroneous values will be saved to the model also - it'd be better to return undefined I believe (when the value is not valid).

Comment: +1 @georgiosd... 100% correct. Looking through what Angular does, they're returning undefined. It's probably not a *big* deal to return the value, as (hopefully) models from invalid forms aren't submitted... but better safe than sorry, I suppose.

Comment: Great stuff!  If you Googled your way here looking for a good writeup on custom validation in Angular, check out what @blesh wrote

Comment: Did you check [Advanced form validation with AngularJS and filters](http://blog.projectnibble.org/2014/01/05/advanced-form-validation-with-angularjs-and-filters/)? It solves the filter validation generically.

Comment: To make it work with the new ngMessages module the "ngModel.$parsers.unshift" should be "return value;" or it would show always the required message error instead of the correct message.

Comment: Not a bad answer but how does it answer the question: "if these 3 fields are filled in, then this field is required and needs to be formatted in a particular way". I need simple validation where either email or phone needs to be provided. If both are empty then it's "Please provide valid email or phone" is one of them is filled but invalid then it's "Please provide a valid email/phone". I was wondering how to access other inputs/values from the validate function as it's only passed the viewValue and control, not the form as a whole.

Comment: @HMR, If your form is set up correctly, you just have to do this: `<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required && myForm.phone.$error.required">Please provide email/phone</span>` and `<span ng-show="(!myForm.email.$error.required && myForm.email.$error.email) || (!myForm.phone.$error.required || !myForm.phone.$error.pattern)">Please provide a valid email/phone</span>`

Comment: @BenLesh Thank you for your reply, that won't work for me because it forces me to define the domain rules in the template(s). Have set up a general directive to be used as a proxy between the template and the rules service but not sure how to get the form: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25309522/1641941

Comment: What if I have custom directive form element. It is not an input. Something like `<div uploader>` And I want to use ngMessage to display error. I know how to create those errors but this. `myForm.email.$error`. How do I build path to that directive? what I place instead of email?

Comment: @BenLesh are `ngMessages` still in beta? Seems, that they are now a full part of `AngularJS 1.3.x`.

Comment: @Eugene no, they're no longer beta, they're in 1.3 which has been released.

Comment: "The first one it finds in the list that is "truthy" wins, and it will show that message and none of the others." <- it would be great to have an option to show all messages instead of only the first one. I prefer seeing all my mistakes at once instead of hitting Submit and being "accused" for next error, and then next and so on.

Comment: Why is it "preferrable to substitute `ng-if` for `ng-show`"

Comment: @Petah really, it's case-by-case ng-if will teardown/setup directives under itself, and prevent leaving things wired up that don't need to be. But in simpler use cases like this, it probably doesn't matter that much, and it may even be faster to use ng-show, because you don't have to set up bindings and such again on whatever it's showing when it's revealed.

Comment: Why does the `$formaters` (i.e. DOM) section of the directive return `false` for invalid, while the $parsers` (i.e. model) section returns `undefined`?  Why do they not both return  `undefined`?

Comment: @BenLesh could one through validator somehow say, that when some validator fails, then in the message connected to this validator use some variable. For example if validator checks for text length, then it is user friendly to tell, what is the expected length. Could one do that with `ngMessages`?

Comment: Yes, you could do that @Eugene. It would only be tricky if the desired length was somehow dynamic. But even that I suspect wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I think you may have meant to do `return value ? valid : undefined` above.

Comment: @BenLesh Can you please share the validation for a checkbox set and not just a single checkbox value using ng-messages ?

Comment: Isn't this a little out of date? `$validators` are the suggested method in AngularJS 1.3 and on. https://busypeoples.github.io/post/forms-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 96):

Angular-UI's project includes a ui-validate directive, which will probably help you with this. It let's you specify a function to call to do the validation.

Have a look at the demo page: http://angular-ui.github.com/, search down to the Validate heading.

From the demo page:

```
<input ng-model="email" ui-validate='{blacklist : notBlackListed}'>
<span ng-show='form.email.$error.blacklist'>This e-mail is black-listed!</span>
```

then in your controller:

```
function ValidateCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.blackList = ['bad@domain.example','verybad@domain.example'];
  $scope.notBlackListed = function(value) {
    return $scope.blackList.indexOf(value) === -1;
  };
}
```

Comment: How strange that this doesn't work for me using Angular 1.4

Comment: Demo link no longer works

Answer (score 47):

You can use  ng-required for your validation scenario ("if these 3 fields are filled in, then this field is required":

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" ng-model="field1" placeholder="Field1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="field2" placeholder="Field2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="field3" placeholder="Field3">
    <input type="text" ng-model="dependentField" placeholder="Custom validation"
        ng-required="field1 && field2 && field3">
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me. For simple validations that depends on other fields values, this is the way to go instead of writting complex validations rules

Answer (score 28):

You can use [Angular-Validator](https://github.com/turinggroup/angular-validator).

**Example: using a function to validate a field**

```
<input  type = "text"
    name = "firstName"
    ng-model = "person.firstName"
    validator = "myCustomValidationFunction(form.firstName)">
```

Then in your controller you would have something like

```
$scope.myCustomValidationFunction = function(firstName){ 
   if ( firstName === "John") {
       return true;
    }
```

**You can also do something like this:**

```
<input  type = "text"
        name = "firstName"
        ng-model = "person.firstName"
        validator = "'!(field1 && field2 && field3)'"
        invalid-message = "'This field is required'">
```

(where field1 field2, and field3 are scope variables. You might also want to check if the fields do not equal the empty string)

If the field does not pass the `validator` then the field will be marked as invalid and the user will not be able to submit the form.

For more use cases and examples see: https://github.com/turinggroup/angular-validator

*Disclaimer: I am the author of Angular-Validator*

Answer (score 15):

I recently created a directive to allow for expression-based invalidation of angular form inputs.  Any valid angular expression can be used, and it supports custom validation keys using object notation.  Tested with angular v1.3.8

```
        .directive('invalidIf', [function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

                var argsObject = scope.$eval(attrs.invalidIf);

                if (!angular.isObject(argsObject)) {
                    argsObject = { invalidIf: attrs.invalidIf };
                }

                for (var validationKey in argsObject) {
                    scope.$watch(argsObject[validationKey], function (newVal) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity(validationKey, !newVal);
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

You can use it like this:

```
<input ng-model="foo" invalid-if="{fooIsGreaterThanBar: 'foo > bar',
                                   fooEqualsSomeFuncResult: 'foo == someFuncResult()'}/>
```

Or by just passing in an expression (it will be given the default validationKey of "invalidIf")

```
<input ng-model="foo" invalid-if="foo > bar"/>
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's a cool way to do custom wildcard expression validations in a form (from: [Advanced form validation with AngularJS and filters](http://blog.bennybottema.com/2014/01/05/advanced-form-validation-with-angularjs-and-filters/)):

```html
<form novalidate="">  
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="newPerson.name"
      ensure-expression="(persons | filter:{name: newPerson.name}:true).length !== 1">
   <!-- or in your case:-->
   <input type="text" id="fruitName" name="fruitName" ng-model="data.fruitName"
      ensure-expression="(blacklist | filter:{fruitName: data.fruitName}:true).length !== 1">
</form>
```

```js
app.directive('ensureExpression', ['$http', '$parse', function($http, $parse) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ngModelController) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
                var booleanResult = $parse(attrs.ensureExpression)(scope);
                ngModelController.$setValidity('expression', booleanResult);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/LS8rt/) (supports expression naming and multiple expressions)

It's similar to `ui-validate`, but you don't need a scope specific validation function (this works generically) and ofcourse you don't need *ui.utils* this way.

Comment: Thanks. Very cool. It is specially useful to apply validation rules for dynamic forms. However, it still set model value even it is invalid. Anyway to prevent it set the modelValue if it is invalid?

Answer (score 5):

@synergetic I think @blesh suppose to put function validate as below

```
function validate(value) {
    var valid = blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1;
    ngModel.$setValidity('blacklist', valid);
    return valid ? value : undefined;
}

ngModel.$formatters.unshift(validate);
ngModel.$parsers.unshift(validate);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

Improved and simplified version of previous directive (one instead of two) with same functionality:

```
.directive('myTestExpression', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var expr = attrs.myTestExpression;
            var watches = attrs.myTestExpressionWatch;

            ctrl.$validators.mytestexpression = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                return expr == undefined || (angular.isString(expr) && expr.length < 1) || $parse(expr)(scope, { $model: modelValue, $view: viewValue }) === true;
            };

            if (angular.isString(watches)) {
                angular.forEach(watches.split(",").filter(function (n) { return !!n; }), function (n) {
                    scope.$watch(n, function () {
                        ctrl.$validate();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

Example usage:

```
<input ng-model="price1" 
       my-test-expression="$model > 0" 
       my-test-expression-watch="price2,someOtherWatchedPrice" />
<input ng-model="price2" 
       my-test-expression="$model > 10" 
       my-test-expression-watch="price1" 
       required />
```

Result: Mutually dependent test expressions where validators are executed on change of other's directive model and current model.

Test expression has local `$model` variable which you should use to compare it to other variables.

**Previously:**

I've made an attempt to improve @Plantface code by adding extra directive. This extra directive very useful if our expression needs to be executed when changes are made in more than one ngModel variables.

```
.directive('ensureExpression', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        controller: function () { },
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.validate = function () {
                var booleanResult = $parse(attrs.ensureExpression)(scope);
                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('expression', booleanResult);
            };

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
                scope.validate();
            });
        }
    };
}])

.directive('ensureWatch', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ensureExpression',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            angular.forEach(attrs.ensureWatch.split(",").filter(function (n) { return !!n; }), function (n) {
                scope.$watch(n, function () {
                    scope.validate();
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Example how to use it to make cross validated fields:

```
<input name="price1"
       ng-model="price1" 
       ensure-expression="price1 > price2" 
       ensure-watch="price2" />
<input name="price2" 
       ng-model="price2" 
       ensure-expression="price2 > price3" 
       ensure-watch="price3" />
<input name="price3" 
       ng-model="price3" 
       ensure-expression="price3 > price1 && price3 > price2" 
       ensure-watch="price1,price2" />
```

`ensure-expression` is executed to validate model when `ng-model` or any of `ensure-watch` variables is changed.

Answer (score 5):

## Custom Validations that call a Server

Use the [ngModelController `$asyncValidators` API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators) which handles asynchronous validation, such as making an `$http` request to the backend. Functions added to the object must return a promise that must be resolved when valid or rejected when invalid. In-progress async validations are stored by key in `ngModelController.$pending`. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms (Custom Validation)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation).

```
ngModel.$asyncValidators.uniqueUsername = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
  var value = modelValue || viewValue;

  // Lookup user by username
  return $http.get('/api/users/' + value).
     then(function resolved() {
       //username exists, this means validation fails
       return $q.reject('exists');
     }, function rejected() {
       //username does not exist, therefore this validation passes
       return true;
     });
};
```

For more information, see

- [ngModelController `$asyncValidators` API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms (Custom Validation)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation).

---

### Using the `$validators` API

The accepted answer uses the `$parsers` and `$formatters` pipelines to add a custom synchronous validator. AngularJS 1.3+ added a `$validators` API so there is no need to put validators in the `$parsers` and `$formatters` pipelines:

```
app.directive('blacklist', function (){ 
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {           
          ngModel.$validators.blacklist = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
              var blacklist = attr.blacklist.split(',');
              var value = modelValue || viewValue;
              var valid = blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1;
              return valid;
          });    
      }
   };
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference - $validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators).

Answer (score 3):

In AngularJS the best place to define Custom Validation is Cutsom directive.
AngularJS provide a ngMessages module.

> ngMessages is a directive that is designed to show and hide messages
>   based on the state of a key/value object that it listens on. The
>   directive itself complements error message reporting with the ngModel
>   $error object (which stores a key/value state of validation errors).

For custom form validation One should use ngMessages Modules with custom directive.Here i have a simple validation which will check if number length is less then 6 display an error on screen

```
 <form name="myform" novalidate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name='test' type='text' required  ng-model='test' custom-validation></td>
                        <td ng-messages="myform.test.$error"><span ng-message="invalidshrt">Too Short</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Here is how to create custom validation directive

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngMessages']);
        angular.module('myApp',['ngMessages']).directive('customValidation',function(){
            return{
            restrict:'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link:function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {// 4th argument contain model information 

            function validationError(value) // you can use any function and parameter name 
                {
                 if (value.length > 6) // if model length is greater then 6 it is valide state
                 {
                 ctrl.$setValidity('invalidshrt',true);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                 ctrl.$setValidity('invalidshrt',false) //if less then 6 is invalide
                 }

                 return value; //return to display  error 
                }
                ctrl.$parsers.push(validationError); //parsers change how view values will be saved in the model
            }
            };
        });
```

`$setValidity` is inbuilt function to set model state to valid/invalid

Answer (score 1):

I extended @Ben Lesh's answer with an ability to specify whether the validation is case sensitive or not (default)

use:

```
<input type="text" name="fruitName" ng-model="data.fruitName" blacklist="Coconuts,Bananas,Pears" caseSensitive="true" required/>
```

code:

```
angular.module('crm.directives', []).
directive('blacklist', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                'blacklist': '=',
            },
            link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs, modelCtrl) {

                var check = function (value) {
                    if (!$attrs.casesensitive) {
                        value = (value && value.toUpperCase) ? value.toUpperCase() : value;

                        $scope.blacklist = _.map($scope.blacklist, function (item) {
                            return (item.toUpperCase) ? item.toUpperCase() : item
                        })
                    }

                    return !_.isArray($scope.blacklist) || $scope.blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1;
                }

                //For DOM -> model validation
                modelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                    var valid = check(value);
                    modelCtrl.$setValidity('blacklist', valid);

                    return value;
                });
                //For model -> DOM validation
                modelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                    modelCtrl.$setValidity('blacklist', check(value));
                    return value;
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some great examples and libs presented in this thread, but they didn't quite have what I was looking for. My approach: [angular-validity](https://github.com/2Toad/Angular-Validity) -- a promise based validation lib for asynchronous validation, with optional Bootstrap styling baked-in.

An angular-validity solution for the OP's use case might look something like this:

```
<input  type="text" name="field4" ng-model="field4"
        validity="eval"
        validity-eval="!(field1 && field2 && field3 && !field4)"
        validity-message-eval="This field is required">
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zze8yste/), if you want to take it for a spin. The lib is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/2Toad/Angular-Validity), has detailed documentation, and plenty of live demos.