# How to validate an AngularJS directive that contains selects?

Tags: angularjs, validation, html-select

I created a directive which is made by 2 selects, that loads the options from 2 json file:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7kK66c?p=preview

As you can see it works fine, but I would like to put this directive into a form, and check its validity. To be more specific I would like this directive to be valid only if the user selected an option from both selects (just like both have been marked with required). I found fields of tutorial about how to set the validy of directive that contains input text, but I nothing to check on selects...how could I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angular-js-form

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **templateDir.html** on [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dxXvDA) for a solution.

You would need to:

- Add a `<form></form>` wrapper with a `name="..."` attribute.
- Add an `ng-model="..."` attribute to each of the `<select></select>` tags.
- Add `ng-required="true"` to each of the `<select></select>` tags.

You can then check whether or not the form is in a valid state using `formName.$invalid`.

The `ng-model` tells Angular to bind the values of those inputs to the variable name you specify in your model and the `ng-required` tells Angular that those two inputs must be completed. I'm assuming the purpose of `<form></form>` is obvious. :)

Comment: This works fine, but I would like a way to get the value of myForm.$invalid to index.html ...

Comment: I updated the Plunker. The `<form></form>` tag needs to be moved into `index.html` so that the form is within scope.