# How can I globbaly configure angularjs email validation pattern

Tags: angularjs

I want to globally change the pattern that angular.js uses to validate email fields.

By default it says that this is valid:

```
somone@domain
```

I want to modify it to require the presence of a `tld`

Does angular expose a global config setting for this?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angular-js-form

Answer (score 0):

There are three options available: to change `EMAIL_REGEXP` variable in angular.js file (this variable doesn't exposed), apply `pattern` validator or implement custom validator.
The second IMO metter way:

```
<div ng-form='myForm' >
  <input type='email' name='email' ng-model='email' ng-pattern='/tld/i' />
  <span ng-show='myForm.email.$error.email' >Invalid email address</span>
  <span ng-show='myForm.email.$error.pattern' >Only corporate email addresses accepted</span>
</div>
```