# AngularJS Custom Validation Bool Method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, customvalidator

I have a method in my angular controller that returns true or false.

```
$scope.overallAmount = function () {
            var cnt = $scope.orders.length, sum = 0;
            while (cnt--) 
                sum += parseFloat(($scope.orders[cnt].CardAmount || 0) * ($scope.orders[cnt].Quantity || 0)) || 0;
            return (500 - sum) > 0;
        };
```

I'd like to use this for validation. Is it possible to create custom validation  that just uses a scope method's true or false to validate? A snippet would be helpful, thanks

Comment: [How to add custom validation to an AngularJS form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12581439/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)’s `ui-validate` directive:

```
<input ui-validate="overallAmount()" />
```