# AngularJS: Custom validator trying to validate immediately

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form where some of the inputs are hooked up to a custom validator via a directive.  The input should validate on blur, and does so via an asynchronous REST API call.

HTML:

```
<input type="text"
   validate-this
   ng-model="thisField"
   ng-model-options="{'updateOn': 'blur'}"
   ng-pattern="some pattern"
/>
```

Directive (shortened for brevity):

```
return {
  access: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  scope: false,
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    ngModel.$asyncValidators.validateThis = function (modelVal, viewVal) {
      if (!modelVal && !viewVal) return $q.defer().promise;

      // returns a promise from the api service
      return api.doSomeValidation();
    };
  }
};
```

The above code works perfectly, but notice the hackish line directly below the validation function signature:

`if (!modelVal && !viewVal) return $q.defer().promise;`

Without that line, Angular attempts to validate the field immediately on application load instead of only on blur.  This is a problem as the actual validation code does some string parsing, and since both `modelVal` and `viewVal` are `undefined`, JavaScript throws an error.

I have tried disabling the functionality that loads data into the fields when the application loads, and the error still happens.  The pattern specified in `ng-pattern`, however, **does** respect my wishes and only validates on field blur--it does NOT attempt to validate on page load. Is there any way to tell Angular to **only** validate on blur, or to get it to stop trying to validate as soon as the page loads?  Or am I using `$asyncValidators` incorrectly?

Comment: [How to add custom validation to an AngularJS form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12581439/6521116)

Answer (score 2):

Angular executes the $validate during the signal of each attr.$observe for the input validations directives such as ngPattern.  You can see that in their patternDirective function.

I have been trying to find a way around this as I use many of the input validations (pattern, max length, required, etc.) and my $asyncValidators are triggering 7 times during load.  This caused the web server to execute for each trigger.

Solutions:

- cache the web method response
- attach your handler after the page load (or have some type of flag)
- bake the ngPattern test into your async handler.  I would probably go with this one.

  ```
  ngModel.$asyncValidators.validateThis = function (modelVal, viewVal) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      if (!modelVal && !viewVal)
          deferred.resolve();
      else if (!myPattern.test(modelVal))
          deferred.reject();
      else
          api.doSomeValidation(value).then(function (result) {
              deferred.resolve();
          }, function (result) {
              deferred.reject();
          })

      return deferred.promise;
  };
  ```

Hopefully this helps as I am in the same boat looking for a solution.