# Why does adding additional AngularJS validation directives cause $asyncValidators to run multiple times?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

Why does adding additional AngularJS validation directives cause `$asyncValidators` to run multiple times on page load?

I created a custom directive which implements $asyncValidators.  This is the basic structure of that custom directive:

```
myApp.directive('userSaved',['$q','userLookup',function($q, userLookup){
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
    ctrl.$asyncValidators.userSaved = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
      // do stuff 
    }
  }
}
}]);
```

The controller initializes the `tailNumber` model value like this:

```
$scope.tailNumber = 'N33221';
```

This is the html where the `user-saved` directive runs **3 times** on page load:

```
<input ng-model="tailNumber" name="tailNumber"   user-saved 
    ng-minlength="2"   ng-pattern="/^[A-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" >
```

When I remove `ng-minlength="2"` then the `user-saved` directive runs twice on page load (**2 times**).  This is the html with `ng-minlength="2"` removed:

```
<input ng-model="tailNumber" name="tailNumber"   user-saved 
    ng-pattern="/^[A-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" >
```

When I remove `ng-pattern="/^[A-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"` then the `user-saved` directive only runs **1 time**.  This is the html after removing `ng-pattern="/^[A-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"`

```
<input ng-model="tailNumber" name="tailNumber" user-saved >
```

Why does my function registered with `$asyncValidators` run an additional time for each additional ng validator attached to the form element?

My custom directive is an expensive `$http` call, and I prefer my custom directive only run once on page load.  Is it possible to use all of these ng validators and while only running my async validator function one time instead of 3 times on page load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because validation directives like `ngMaxlength`, `ngPattern` invoke an initial validation cycle with a call to `ngModelController.$validate()`.

This causes all the validation directive to run their validation logic, including the async validators.

One way to prevent the redundant `$http` calls, and in fact it is a good practice anyway, is to cache the validation result for each input.

Comment: The documentation says ngModelController will run _first synchronous validators and then asynchronous validators_.  So why is ngModelController running my asynchronous directive while running the synchronous `ngMinlength` and `ngPattern`?

Comment: @steampowered, right - first sync, and if they succeed, then async... The sync validators clearly succeed (which [they](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/directive/validators.js#L47) [do](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/directive/validators.js#L68) for empty values, for example), then async validators run

Comment: @steampowered, did this address your question?

Comment: The answer was helpful but I think there might be more going on with this issue.  The `ngMinlength` and `ngPattern` should run synchronously before the ansyn validator runs, which is not happening.  I ended up removing the `ngMinlength` and `ngPattern` validators because they didn't play nicely with an `$asyncvalidators` implementation (I removed all the code in the directive, but still my bare directive caused problems with the `ngMinlength` and `ngPattern` validators).  So I have working code, but I think there may be more going on here than this answer addresses.

Comment: @steampowered, what makes you say that `ngMinlength` and `ngPattern` do not run synchronously? They do. If you are uncertain, put breakpoints in their src code (e.g. [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/directive/validators.js#L84)).

Comment: It was my understanding from reading the docs that non-async validators such as ngMinlength and ngPattern would not call asyncrhonous validators.  The docs seemed to indicate all synchronous validation would complete prior to asynchronous validation being attempted.  However, this is not the case apparently.  Anyway, your answer was helpful and did add to my understanding.  I am marking your answer correct now.

Comment: @steampowered, we might be talking about the same thing in different terms. `ngModel` calls sync validators - if they all pass, then it will call async validators. Any directive that has `require: "ngModel"` can call `ngModel.$validate()` to start the validation pipeline from the beginning, and `ngMinlength` and other validators do exactly that in their `attrs.$observe`. In fact, you have to account for that fact, because in the future someone might add another directive with `require: "ngModel"` in addition to your async validator, which is why I said that caching is anyway a good practice

Comment: I did end up caching after you suggested it, thanks for the tip.  I'll look into `ngModel.$validate()`

Comment: Any news on this? I'm running on the same situation

Comment: How would you cache the validation result?

Comment: @endamaco, like you would cache anything else... you store the input and the validation result in some in-memory data-structure, like a hash

Comment: Is there a way to only validate when something was changed? Why do we need to run validators on the form load? I only want to run validations if I changed the value. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you please show an example? Would overwriting the $validators.maxlength help?

Answer (score 3):

It actually took me a while to figure this one out. As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27407753/4706977) post, Angular validators trigger additional  validations. I decided not to fight this behavior and work around it instead, falling back to parsers and formatters:

```
myApp.directive('userSaved',['$q','dataservice',function($q, dataservice){
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
    ctrl.$parsers.unshift(checkUserSaved);
    ctrl.$formatters.unshift(checkUserSaved);

    function checkUserSaved(value){
        ctrl.$setValidity("usersaved") // the absence of the state parameter sets $pending to true for this validation
        dataservice.getUserSaved(value).then(function(response){
            var userIsSaved = (response === true);

            ctrl.$setValidity("usersaved", userIsSaved); // the presence of the state parameter removes $pending for this validation

            return userIsSaved ? value : undefined;
        });

        return value;
    }
  }
}
}]);
```

As a reference, you also might want to check the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

**EDIT**

Upon further investigation, it appears that in the case of ng-pattern the extra validations are only triggered when the regex is converted from a string.

Passing the regex directly:

```
<div ng-pattern="/^[0-9]$/" user-saved></div>
```

fixed the problem for me while making use of the validators pipeline.

For reference, see [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12913)

Answer (score 1):

I followed @New Dev's advice and implemented a simple caching routine which fulfilled my requirement quite nicely, here's what I came up with ..

```
link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

        var cache = {};
        ngModel.$asyncValidators.validateValue = function (modelValue) {
            if (modelValue && cache[modelValue] !== true) {
                return MyHttpService.validateValue(modelValue).then(function (resolved) {
                    cache[modelValue] = true; // cache 
                    return resolved;
                }, function(rejected) {
                    cache[modelValue] = false;
                    return $q.reject(rejected);
                });
            } else {
                return $q.resolve("OK");
            }
        };
    }
```