# How to add directive for extra validation properly in angular?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

What I need: I need to add extra validation to input by adding attribute to this input.

Firstly, my plnkr example is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Vztp3XtZ8w7aQ6oRhC5?p=preview)

What I'd tried?: I added directive, so when I add attribute to the input, the value of the input is being validated by regexp `^5$`. Also, I added required to the input. I am talking about 2nd input now (name of the input is `input2`).

So, I'd added attributes "my-attribute" and "required". When there is nothing in input I expect two items in `myForm.item[1].$error`: its ok – there are properties `myAttribute` and `required`. Now, I will add some to the input2, for example "abc", now I expect in `myForm.item[1].$error` only `myAttribute` property (because required validation is passed, but `myAttribute` validation is not), but there is properties `myAttribute` and `parse` in `myForm.item[1].$error`. What is `parse` property? Why it is adding to `$error`?

I should notice, that when I put 5 to the input2 `myForm.item[1].$error` is empty, because both require and myAttribute validations passed (and this behaviour is expected).

Now, when I clear input2 there are properties `parse` and `myAttribute` again. Why? When field input2 is empty, I expect `required` and `myAttribute` in `myForm.item[1].$error`, but there are no ones.

So, why I get strange property `parse` in `$error` and how I can make my example working?

Form example code was founded [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) and approach to validate input by directive was founded in answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angular-js-form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is parse property? Why it is adding to $error?

The `parse` property is automatically added by Angular when one of the parsers returns `undefined`.
From [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers):

> Returning undefined from a parser means a parse error occurred. No
>   $validators will run and the 'ngModel' will not be updated until the
>   parse error is resolved. The parse error is stored in
>   'ngModel.$error.parse'.

Not sure if I'm missing some use case here but changing the `return` clause from the parser should be enough:

```
//For DOM -> model validation
ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
  var valid = new RegExp("^5$").test(value);
  ngModel.$setValidity('myAttribute', valid);
  return value;
});
```

Comment: Ok about parse. But, there is required attribute and I need to work with required first. When the form is blank there must be two properties in error: required and myAttribute, right? Why not? Both validations are not passing. Ok about parse, ok about myAttribute but what about required?

Comment: *"When the form is blank there must be two properties in error: required and myAttribute, right?"* Yes, that's what I'm getting. Aren't you seeing the same? Isn't that the expected behaviour?

Comment: No, when form is blank (not first load, but after inputing some stuff and clearing input) I don't see same

Comment: Please test with this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/USi3E200cUVXJfMcBU0F?p=preview). I'm not able to replicate that behaviour. When I insert and then clean one of the inputs the `require` attribute appears on the `$error` list.