# How can I extend AngularJS model flags on an Angular form?

Tags: angularjs, validation

AngularJS provides what they call 'model flags' on their forms. For example, you can have formName.$dirty, formName.$invalid, etc.  What I want to know is how can I create my own custom flag for my AngularJS forms? A high level demonstration or link to an article would be a sufficient answer.

Comment: The formName is a standard javascript object (FormController to be precise), which you can add properties as you want.

Comment: Thinking of formName as an instance of FormController is definitely getting me in the right direction. Could you show me a way to updated the formName object via a custom validation directive? For example, could I have a directive using ng-model that sets `formName.$warning` when someone types 'bad speling' into the input?

Answer (score 0):

See here: [how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angular-js-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angular-js-form).

In short, this is a custom valitation directive example:

```
app.directive('blacklist', function (){ 
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
          var blacklist = attr.blacklist.split(',');

          // for DOM -> model validation
          ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
             var valid = blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1;
             ngModel.$setValidity('blacklist', valid);
             return valid ? value : undefined;
          });

          //For model -> DOM validation
          ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
             ngModel.$setValidity('blacklist', blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1);
             return value;
          });
      }
   };
});
```

And this it's an example of it's usage:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="doSomething()">
   <input type="text" name="fruitName" ng-model="data.fruitName" blacklist="coconuts,bananas,pears" required/>
   <span ng-show="myForm.fruitName.$error.blacklist">
      The phrase "{{data.fruitName}}" is blacklisted</span>
   <span ng-show="myForm.fruitName.$error.required">required</span>
   <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But, again, read the referenced question and accepted answer, it's by far more complete...

Comment: That's not quite what I was looking for. I want to know how to modify the validity state of the entire form. For example, if someone were to enter a blacklisted fruit, would I be able to set the form controller state to `myForm.$hasBlacklist`?