# Angular custom form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to follow some tutorials, but couldn't figure out what to do.

I would like to add the validation, that at least one of the checkboxes (consumer/vendor) has to be true. If not true show an error message at both fields). What would be the easiest way to accomplish that?

```
<form role="form" name="addClientForm" ng-submit="submitForm(addClientForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addClientForm.title.$invalid && !addClientForm.title.$pristine }">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a title" ng-model="client.title" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addClientForm.company.$invalid && !addClientForm.company.$pristine }">
            <label>Company</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a company" ng-model="client.company" required>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label class="i-checks">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="client.consumer"><i></i> Consumer
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label class="i-checks">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="client.vendor"><i></i> Vendor
          </label>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Controller (modal controller)

```
angular.module('App')
  .controller('ModalAddClientCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

    $scope.client = { title: '', company: '', consumer: true, vendor: false };

    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

    };

    $scope.ok = function () {

      $modalInstance.close($scope.client);

    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use angular form validation like you are trying to you have to set name attribute in the input fields. So, if you have a `<form name='form'>` with `<input name='input'>` only then you can use `form.input.$dirty` or  `form.input.$pristine`. Combine that with `ng-if` like you have the rest is simple.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btx6p7wf/) for example and try editing the values. I have implemented validation in your form. I have left out the controller, conditions and error messages could be simpler but you will get the idea.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angular-js-form?rq=1) related post that has an excellent answer on using form validation.