# AngularJS & Laravel - Wizard navigation

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am trying to create a multi form/wizard step navigation. I am using `ng-switch` to create the steps. But I got stuck, this is the relevant code:

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-controller="stepCtrl">
<div ng-switch="step">
   <div ng-switch-when="1">
      <div ng-controller="postAddressDataCtrl">
         <form url="users/createaddress" ng-submit="add()">
            <label class="input-label">
            <span class="label-title">
            Line 1
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="line-1" ng-model="line1" placeholder="Line 1">
            </label>

            <label class="input-label">
            <span class="label-title">
            Line 2
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="line-2" ng-model="line2" placeholder="Line 2">
            </label>

            <label class="input-label">
            <span class="label-title">
            City
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="city" placeholder="City">
            </label>

            <label class="input-label">
            <span class="label-title">
            Postcode
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="postcode" ng-model="postcode" placeholder="Postcode">
            </label>

            <label class="input-label">
            <span class="label-title">
            Country
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="country" ng-model="country" placeholder="Country">
            </label>

            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="form-group">
               {{ Form::button('Save Address', array('type'=>'submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'style' => 'width:100%;')) }}
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
      <button ng-click="setStep(2)">Step 2</button>
   </div>
   <div ng-switch-when="2">
      Step 2 - another form
      <button ng-click="setStep(1)">Step 1</button>
      <button ng-click="setStep(3)">Step 3</button>
   </div>
   <div ng-switch-when="3">
      Step 3 - another form
      <button ng-click="setStep(2)">Step 2</button>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

**Controllers:**

*stepCtrl*

```
myApp.controller('stepCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.step = 1;
    $scope.setStep = function(step){
        $scope.step = step;
    } 
});
```

*postAddressDataCtrl*

```
myApp.controller('postAddressDataCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'CSRF_TOKEN', function($scope, $http, CSRF_TOKEN) {
    $scope.urlpath = '{{ url('/') }}';
    $scope.add = function() {
        var line1 = $scope.line1;
        var line2 = $scope.line2;
        var city = $scope.city;
        var postcode = $scope.postcode;
        var country = $scope.country;

        return $http({
            url: "/users/createaddress",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                'line1': line1,
                'line2': line2,
                'city': city,
                'postcode': postcode,
                'country': country,
                '_token': CSRF_TOKEN
            },
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log(data);
              if (data.status == 200) {
                  // move to the next step
              }
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log(data);
        });
    };
}]);
```

How can I check if the data entered in the form are valid and if they are then to move in the next step with a single button?

*How can I set the `step` equal to `2` when the `data.status` is equal to `200`, so only then it will move on?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Angular's form validation. For example add `required` to your input field if you want to require the field and `ng-minlength` or `ng-maxlength` for character limits. You can also write [custom validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angular-js-form) if you need specific validation on certain fields.

To change the step you can increment your step variable inside ng-submit.
To increment only if your `$http` request is successful you can put it directly in your `.success` function.

```
<form url="users/createaddress" ng-submit="add()" novalidate>
    <label class="input-label">
        <span class="label-title">
        Line 1
        </span>
        <input type="text" name="line-1" ng-model="line1" placeholder="Line 1" ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=20 required>
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Address</button>
</form>
```

postAddressDataCtrl

```
myApp.controller('postAddressDataCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'CSRF_TOKEN', function($scope, $http, CSRF_TOKEN) {
    $scope.urlpath = '{{ url('/') }}';
    $scope.add = function() {
        var line1 = $scope.line1;
        var line2 = $scope.line2;
        var city = $scope.city;
        var postcode = $scope.postcode;
        var country = $scope.country;

        return $http({
            url: "/users/createaddress",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                'line1': line1,
                'line2': line2,
                'city': city,
                'postcode': postcode,
                'country': country,
                '_token': CSRF_TOKEN
            },
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log(data);
              if (data.status == 200) {
                  // move to the next step
                  $scope.step += 1;
              }
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log(data);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. Although, I have one concern how can I prevent the step from increasing `+1` if the request got back in the `add()` function equals to a response code `400` (which this might be the occasion if the backend validation fails)? Basically I think it should be more appropriate if the step gets increased if I the response code `200`.

Comment: You can change `step = step + 1` to be a function like `incrementStep()` where you can check the response code in your controller and increase the step if necessary.

Comment: Can you include an example please?

Comment: I updated my answer. You should just be able to increment the step inside your `.success` function

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I am not sure if this is going to work because `$scope.step` is inside the `stepCtrl` therefore I think that `postAddressDataCtrl` won't know about it.

Comment: It should work because `postAddressDataCtrl` is nested inside `stepCtrl` so it should have access to its scope.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, got it working! Although I had to do  `$scope.$parent.$parent.step += 1;`