# How to add custom form validation inside angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm trying to implement custom form validation with angular for an email input . I would like the input to be valid only with the appropriate domain (here that is @example.com).

The code below works, EXCEPT that it runs before the HTML form is initialized, triggering the error: **"TypeError: Cannot read property '$error' of undefined"**

```
app.controller('TeamSignInController', function($scope) {

    $scope.domain = "@example.com";

    var EMAIL_REGEXP = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+" + $scope.domain + "$", "i");
    $scope.form.$error.required[0].$validators.email = function (modelValue) {
        return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(modelValue);
    }

}
```

What is the best way to set up custom form validation in an angular controller so that it **only initializes once the form element is fully loaded?** I've tried using ng-init on the form, but that fires before each form *element* has fully loaded.

And here's the HTML:

```
<section id="teamSignIn">
  <form name="form" ng-submit="loginUser(credentials)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control text-left input-lg" placeholder="you@example.com" ng-model="credentials.email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control text-left input-lg" placeholder="password" ng-model="credentials.password" required>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-blue" type="submit">
      Sign in
    </button>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angular-js-form

Comment: So should I infer that there is no way to do this without using a custom directive? Not that it's an incredible hassle.