# Setting up multiple forms / validations on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

What's up all, total AngularJS noob here and looking for some answers.

I have a page set up like so:

```
    <form name="mainForm" class="content" ng-app="pathForm" ng-controller="FormControl" novalidate>

    <div class="full-page open" id="form1">
    <!-- Form 1 content here -->
    </div>  

    <div class="full-page" id="form2">
    <!-- Form 2 content here -->
    </div>

    <div class="full-page" id="form3">
    <!-- Form 3 content here -->
    </div>

    <div class="full-page" id="form4">
    <!-- Form 4 content here -->
    </div>

</form>
```

Where each of these forms have their own set of inputs that need validation. I've been able to get the validation working across all four forms, because I set up an encompassing form ng-app that cover all 4 forms. On submit, a script removes the 'open' class from the open form, cycles to the enxt form and adds the open class on that form.

How can I set it so that each one of these forms can be individually validated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [ngForm directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) and [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

Each ng-form directive with name in this directive adds property to the `$scope`. You can access this property (it is object, instance of FormController) in function called by submit button click.

There are some properties and methods in this object. You need property `$valid` (or `$invalid`) to get validation status of your forms.

HTML:

```
<ng-form name="form1"></ng-form>
<ng-form name="form2"></ng-form>
<button ng-click="submit();">Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    if ($scope.form1.$valid && $scope.form2.$valid) {}
}
```

**Custom validators**
If built-in validators are not enought you can add your own custom validators.

See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angularjs-form) on so.com.