# How to set AngularJS validation in JavaScript and not HTML elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am using angular form validation like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" ng-model="name" ng-required="true" name="name" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[validationForm.name.$invalid]" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
<p ng-show="validationForm.name.$error.required && validationForm.name.$dirty">
    Name is required.
</p>
```

A lot of the HTML Code is used only for the validation - 4 attributes in the input element. Is it possible to set only 1 attribute for "custom validation" and implement the other stuff in my JavaScript code? I think that would result in cleaner code and save a lot of time if I have ~20 inputs.

Comment: Check out this question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angularjs-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't use `ng-repeat`?

```
<div ng-repeat"item in items">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{item.id}}" ng-model="item.model" ng-required="item.required" name="{{item.name}}" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[validationForm.{{item.name}}.$invalid]" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
    <p ng-show="validationForm.{{item.name}}.$error.required && validationForm.{{item.name}}.$dirty">
       {{item.errorMessage}}
    </p>
</div>
```

and then in your controller

```
$scope.items = [{
    id: "id1",
    name: "name1",
    model: "your starting value",
    errorMessage: "Name is required.",
    required: true,
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

**Edit:**

You can use a custom `directive` to do the same at different locations

```
<my-input  data="items[0]" myform="validationForm"></my-input>
```

and then your directive

```
.directive('myInput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        data: '=',
        myform: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'myInput.html'
  };
});
```

Content of `myInput.html`

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{data.id}}" ng-model="data.model" ng-required="data.required" name="{{data.name}}" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[myform.{{data.name}}.$invalid]" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
    <p ng-show="myform.{{data.name}}.$error.required && myform.{{data.name}}.$dirty">
       {{data.errorMessage}}
    </p>
```

Comment: My form is more an application so I dont have all inputs in the same container.

Comment: That looks nice. I will try it tomorrow. Thank you! :)