# Custom validation on Angular Form - on blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

In Angular, I am trying to validate a value of a field on blur. I have a list of customers, and I want to check if the model value in the field is in my list of customers. If not, I want to set the validity to false.

I know that `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}` exists, however, I can't use this because the field is a typeahead so it must update based on the model. The validation is what needs to happen on blur.

The answer seems to be:

1. Write it as a function in the controller and use $setValidity just as you would in a directive. Use ng-blur to trigger the function in the input field.

   -However, I keep running into examples where a custom validation (make the field invalid if the model value does not match one in the list) is only written as a directive. Are there examples of custom validation written as a function?
2. Write a directive that only triggers on blur.

However, I can't find examples that do either of these things. Does anybody have an example of custom validation as a function OR a directive that only updates on blur of the field?

I found this link very helpful for custom validation but I still have the same problem with the difference between a function and a directive: [How to add custom validation to an AngularJS form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angularjs-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As something we've been working on recently:

```
<form name='vm.formName' id='vm.formName' novalidate>
  <input type='text' id='textField' name='textField' ng-blur='vm.blurMethod()' ng-model='vm.model.text' />
  // The submit is only here for show;
  <input type='submit' id='submit' ng-click='vm.submitForm()' />
</form>
```

In the controller:

```
blurMethod() {
  if (this.formName.textField.$viewValue !== myArbitraryValue) {
    // $setValidity called on the form, setting the textfield's validity to false
    // then you can have your own validators show the error in the template
    this.formName.$setValidity('textField', false);
  }
}
```

That's off the top of my head, will take a look in the morning to see if it mirrors what we've been using. Updated the $setValidity call now.

This assumes you're using the controllerAs: 'vm' syntax, which is why the form has a name 'vm.formname' and the controller is using 'this'.

Comment: this looks promising, looking forward to the update tomorrow

Comment: Hey rrd, any luck finding if it matches what you've been using?

Comment: Yeah I updated the post, it's what we were using. the $setValidity() is called on the form and takes the input field as the argument.

Comment: Accepted your answer, had to tweak for my solution but you led me to the right place. Only annoying thing is that apparently selecting on a typeahead counts as a "blur" action so it runs through the function twice.

Answer (score 1):

I have used ui-bootstrap for typeahead with plenty of control on your validation [ui-bootstrap typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

**EDIT- Code sample**

`<input type="text" ng-model="selected" 
    typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
    class="form-control"
    typeahead-no-results="$scope.matchFail">
    <div ng-show="$scope.matchFail">Not on list!!</div>`

When you choose a value that is not on the list, the div is displayed

Comment: The typeahead works fine. What kind of validation are you talking about? I want there to be an error in my form if there are no results:  "typeahead-no-results $  (Default: angular.noop) - Binding to a variable that indicates if no matching results were found." Right now it shows that there are no results but it does not throw an error in my form.

Comment: This is not helpful to me. I have the no-results working, it displays the div. That part is simple. What does not work is validation, for example, what is shown in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angularjs-form . In this case, the form should not be able to be submitted if typeahead-no-results shows up. If it helps, the answer below is closer to answering what I am looking for.