# validate certain fields of a form depending upon type of user logged in

Tags: angularjs, node.js, validation, angularjs-validation

i have a form which contain 10 fields, if user type 1 is logged in only one field should be validated else all the fields should be validated.is it possible to validate certain fields depending upon user logged in?

Comment: can you give some more details

Comment: create separate forms n models.. display based on user type

Comment: there are two types of user (user1 &user2) if user1 is logged in,validation should work only for two fields and if he entered values into that field he can save the data; if user2 is logged in validation should work for all the fields

Comment: @Akanksha thx for the suggestion. but there are 100 fields in my form and there are 6 types of users! so i don't want to lengthen my code.is there any other way?

Comment: Use `ng-if` inside the `form`

Comment: u need to create a custom validator directive... for eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angularjs-form
I m still figuring out how to incorporate user type in such validation.

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand i didnt get you,like i said i dont want to use more than one form (I'm new to angularjs)

Comment: What he meant, while developing ur html for form.. use ng-if directives to add or remove validations based on ur user

Comment: I found this http://angularjs.io/how-to-create-a-custom-input-validator-with-angularjs/
Here u cn use custom validator.. here u cn put restrictions on validators based on user type

Comment: thanx @Akanksha for ur time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $scope.required = true; in your controller.Now change the value of $scope.required as per your user who is login. like if login by admin : if(admin){ $scope.required=false; } if(user){ $scope.required=true;}

Thanks

Comment: i wld have to change "required" to "ng-required" in input tag right??

Comment: Yes you would have to change "required" to "ng-required" in input tag