# Directive for restricting typing by Regex in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I coded an angular directive for inhibiting typing from inputs by specifying a regex. In that directive I indicate a regex that will be used for allow the input data. Conceptually, it works fine, but there are two bugs in this solution:

1. In the first [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QK9ZPcuESuXEsht1csyb?p=preview) example the input must allow **only numbers** or **numbers followed by a dot [.]**, or **numbers followed by a dot followed by numbers with no more than four digits**.

   - If I type a value *'1.1111'* and after that I go to the first digit and so type another digit (in order to get a value as *'11.1111'*) , nothing happening. The bug is in the fact I use the expression `elem.val() + event.key` on my regex validator. I do not know how to get the whole 
     current value for a input on a keypress event;
2. The second one is the fact that some characters (grave, acute, tilde, circumflex) are being allowed on typing (press one of them more than once), althought the regex does not allow them.

**What changes do I need to make in my code in order to get an effective type restriction by regex?**

```
  <html ng-app="app">    
  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.6.4" data-semver="1.6.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Restrict typing by RegExp</h1>
    PATTERN 1 (^\d+$|^\d+[.]$|^\d+[.]\d{1,4}$) <input type="text" allow-typing="^\d+$|^\d+[.]$|^\d+[.]\d{1,4}$"/><br>
    ONLY NUMBERS <input type="text" allow-typing="^[0-9]+$"/><br>
    ONLY STRINGS <input type="text" allow-typing="^[a-zA-Z]+$"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('allowTyping', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      var regex = attrs.allowTyping;
      elem.bind('keypress', function(event) {
        var input = elem.val() + event.key;
        var validator = new RegExp(regex);
        if(!validator.test(input)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Your regex should be either `^\d+(?:\.(?:\d{1,4})?)?$` or `^(?:\d+(?:\.(?:\d{1,4})?)?)?$` which is a firmly specific pattern. If it is allowing anything else, something else is wrong.

Comment: What is ?: in your regex?

Comment: @GeisonSantos `(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group. It matches without capturing everything enclosed.

Comment: i think you should bind to event onkeyup instead of onkeypress, so you do not need do elem.val() + event.key any more. this will fix your 1th bug

Comment: @yudongshen, I tried on this way (using onkeyup). Using this approach I would need to replace incorrect characters using the same directive regex, but in a reverse way. Do you have idea of how to do that?

Comment: @GeisonSantos, save value while onkeypress,  and roll back to it if valid failure on event onkeyup. how about this way?

Comment: Btw, if you change it to `^((?:\d+(?:\.(?:\d{1,4})?)?)?).*$`, after a valid input char event (but before display), you could just write back the correction `$1` to the box. Thus, it never shows wrong data and has the illusion of disallowing invalid chars, or ones in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Plnkr Fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/2uEM41TTLsip4N5mDLva?p=preview) as per your approach:

The explanation of why and the changes are explained below.
Side note: I would not implement it this way (use `ngModel` with `$parsers` and `$formatters`, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090867/2103767) - implementing that is beyond the scope of your question. However I found a full implementation by [regexValidate by Ben Lesh](http://www.benlesh.com/2012/12/angular-js-custom-validation-via.html) which will fit your problem domain:-

> If I type a value '1.1111' and after that I go to the first digit and so type another digit (in order to get a value as '11.1111') , nothing happening.

because in your code below

> `var input = elem.val() + event.key;`

you are assuming that the event.key is always appended at the end.

So how to get the position of the correct position and validate the the reconstructed string ? You can use an undocumented `event.target.selectionStart` property. Note even though you are not selecting anything you will have this populated (IE 11 and other browsers). See [Plnkr Fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/2uEM41TTLsip4N5mDLva?p=preview)

> The second one is the fact that some characters (grave, acute, tilde, circumflex) are being allowed on typing (press one of them more than once), althought the regex does not allow them.

Fixed the regex - correct one below:

`^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]{0,4})?$`

So the whole thing looks as below

```
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    var regex = attrs.allowTyping;
    elem.bind('keypress', function(event) {
      var pos = event.target.selectionStart;
      var oldViewValue = elem.val();
      var input = newViewValue(oldViewValue, pos, event.key);
      console.log(input);
      var validator = new RegExp(regex);
      if (!validator.test(input)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });

    function newViewValue(oldViewValue, pos, key) {
      if (!oldViewValue) return key;
      return [oldViewValue.slice(0, pos), key, oldViewValue.slice(pos)].join('');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If this were my code, I'd change tactics entirely: **I would listen for `input` events instead of trying to micromanage the user interactions with the field.**

The approach you are taking, in general, has problems. The biggest one is that **`keypress` won't be emitted for all changes to the field.** Notably,

1. It is not triggered by DELETE and BACKSPACE keys.
2. Input methods can bypass it. When you entered diacritics as diacritics, your code was not registering the change. In general, if the user is using an [input method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method), there is no guarantee that each new character added to the field will result in a `keypress` event. It depends on the method the user has chosen.
3. `keypress` does not help when the user cuts from the field or pastes into the field.

You could add code to try to handle all the cases above, but it would get complex quick. You've already run into an issue with `elem.val() + event.key` because the `keypress` may not *always* be about a character inserted at the end of the field. The user may have moved the caret so you have to keep track of caret position. One comment suggested listening to `keyup` but that does not help with input methods or paste/cut events.

In contrast, the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) is generated when the value of the field changes, as the changes occur. All cases above are taken care of. This, for instance, would work:

```
elem.bind('input', function(event) {
  var validator = new RegExp(regex);
  elem.css("background-color", !validator.test(elem.val()) ? "red" : null);
});
```

This is a minimal illustration that you could plop into your fiddle to replace your current event handler. In a real application, I'd give the user a verbose error message rather than just change the color of the field and I'd create `validator` just once, outside the event handler, but this gives you the idea.

(There's also a `change` event but you do no want to use that. For text fields, it is generated when the focus leaves the field, which is much too late.)

Answer (score 0):

1. You specified 4 different patterns 3 different pattens in your regex separated by an alteration sign: `^\d+$|^\d+[.]$|^\d+[.]\d{1,4}$` - this will not fulfill the criteria of `input must allow only numbers followed by a dot [.], followed by a number with no more than four digits.` The bug "where nothing happens" occurs because the variable you are checking against is not what you think it is, check the screenshot on how you can inspect it, and what it is:

[image]

2. Can not reproduce.

Comment: Mindaugas, I'm sorry. My bad... the first regex, as you see, accepts numbers, or numbers + dot  or numbers + dot + numbers. I will correct the question description. For you get the second bug, you need to use the combination of space + accent (grave, tilde, circumflex).

Comment: Ok, then the regex is usable (could be improved). Did you understand why the first bug is present (for the 11.1111 string)? You are using element data + the key sent on event as input - so it is always added to the end, and not where you want it to be. For the 2nd - still can't reproduce, all works for me. Can you provide steps to reproduce which would identify the field and the precise sequence of actions, like it is  normally done in the software development world?

Comment: "Did you understand why the first bug is present (for the 11.1111 string)? You are using element data + the key sent on event as input - so it is always added to the end, and not where you want it to be." Yes, I knew. I would like to use another approach to get input data... Some suggestion?

Comment: You are using incorrect event handler. The value entered in the field `elem.val()` keypress and keydown is not there, so you try to append it to the end, which can be easily broken. A simple fix would be to use events that happen when the input is there, like `keyup`. Or you can filter on a per-character basis - meaning only allow certain characters and check them one-by-one and then validate the pattern at the end (when the user leaves the field, or presses submit). This is how it is usually done.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the event to `keyup`, so the test would run **after** every additional character is added.

It means you need to save the last valid input, so if the user tries to insert a character that'll turn the string invalid, the test will restore the last valid value.

Hence, the updated directive:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('allowTyping', function()  {
        return {
            restrict : 'A',
            link : function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                var regex = attrs.allowTyping;
                var lastInputValue = "";
                elem.bind('keyup', function(event) {
                var input = elem.val();
                var validator = new RegExp(regex);

                if (!validator.test(input))
                    // Restore last valid input
                    elem.val(lastInputValue).trigger('input');
                else
                    // Update last valid input
                    lastInputValue = input;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```