# AngularJS custom validation directive with dynamic blacklist

Tags: angularjs

I am using the example for ngMessages from this post:

[How to add custom validation to an AngularJS form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angularjs-form)

It works OK as long as the blacklist is a static list of items.

[image: Working validation with static blacklist]

I would like to dynamically generate the blacklist but the directive seems to render before the blacklist is populated.

This is the directive:

```
.directive('blacklist', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            var blacklist = attr.blacklist.split(',');
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('blacklist', blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1);
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This is the input where the directive is used:

```
<input type="text" id="DocumentName" name="DocumentName" class="form-control"
       ng-model="$ctrl.document.DocumentName" ng-required="true"
       blacklist="{{$ctrl.DocumentNames}}" />
```

In the controller when the blacklist is specified with static values it works as expected.

```
    .component('documentDetail', {
    templateUrl: '/app/document-detail/document-detail.template.html',
    controller: ['Document', 
        function DocumentDetailController(Document) {
            var self = this;
            self.DocumentNames = "Install Direct Bill Invoice,Order Preacknowledgement,Order Acknowledgement"; });
```

When this is changed to get the DocumentNames with a service call it seems like the directive is rendered before the blacklist values are populated.

```
component('documentDetail', {
    templateUrl: '/app/document-detail/document-detail.template.html',
    controller: ['Document',  
        function DocumentDetailController(Document) {
            var self = this;
            var documentProfiles = Document.query();
            documentProfiles.$promise.then(function () {
                var bl = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < documentProfiles.length; i++) {
                    bl.push(documentProfiles[i].DocumentName);
                }
                self.DocumentNames = bl.join(',');
            });
```

When I inspect the element I can see the data has been populated:

[image: Inspect Element]

But the validation acts like it is an empty string:

[image: Validation Result]

I tried wrapping it in a $timeout but the result was the same.

```
  component('documentDetail', {
    templateUrl: '/app/document-detail/document-detail.template.html',
    controller: ['Document', '$timeout', 
        function DocumentDetailController(Document, $timeout) {
            var self = this;
            var documentProfiles = Document.query();
            $timeout(function () {
                documentProfiles.$promise.then(function () {
                    var bl = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < documentProfiles.length; i++) {
                        bl.push(documentProfiles[i].DocumentName);
                    }
                    self.DocumentNames = bl.join(',');
                });
            });
```

How can I get these values to populate before the directive or input renders so that the blacklist can be dynamic?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `attr.$observe`:

```
app.directive('blacklist', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            var blacklist = attrs.blacklist.split(',');
            attr.$observe("blacklist",function(newValue) {
                blacklist = newValue.split(',');
            });
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('blacklist', blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1);
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The observer function is invoked whenever the interpolated value changes.

For more information, see [AngularJS attr.$observe API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe)

---

## Update

### Using the `$validators` API<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840247/5535245)</sup>

The accepted answer to the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angularjs-form) uses the `$parsers` and `$formatters` pipelines to add a custom synchronous validator. AngularJS 1.3+ added a `$validators` API so there is no need to put validators in the `$parsers` and `$formatters` pipelines:

```
app.directive('blacklist', function (){ 
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {           
          ngModel.$validators.blacklist = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
              var blacklist = attrs.blacklist.split(',');
              var value = modelValue || viewValue;
              var valid = blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1;
              return valid;
          });    
      }
   };
});
```

Notice that since the `blacklist` is re-computed everytime the ngModelController does a validation, there is no need to add an `$observe` function.

For more information, see [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference - $validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators).