# How can i validate form fields based on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-messages

I have 3 buttons. 2 is inside ng-repeat and one outside ng-repeat so
I want to show the required field alert if the user clicks these buttons.

if the user clicks check 0 I have to validate only the first object and if any form data value missing I have to alert the user like 'this(username) is a required field.

if the user clicks the check 1 button I have to validate only the second object and if any form data value missing I have to alert the user like 'this(username) is a required field.

and if the user click check all button I have to check both the objects and if any field missing in both the objects I have to alert the field name with the object index.

How can I show the required field if the user clicks the check all button and check button please help me

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/as86qxL2/1/)
[image]

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngMessages']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {
        "inputName":"aj",
        "inputPassword":"1234",
        "inputEmail":"aj@g.in",
        },{
        
        "inputName":"gj",
        "inputPassword":"1234",
        "inputEmail":"gj@g.in",
        }
    ];
     $scope.myFunc = function(formValidation) {
        console.log(formValidation)
    };
    $scope.checkall = function(formValidation) {
        console.log(formValidation)
    };
});
```

```html
<body translate="no" >
<button ng-click="checkall(formValidation)">check all</button>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="generic-messages">
    <p ng-message="required">This field is required.</p>
    <p ng-message="minlength">This field is too short.</p>
    <p ng-message="maxlength">This field is too long.</p>
  </script>


  <form name="formValidation">
<button ng-click="myFunc(formValidation)">check {{$index}}</button>
    <label>Username (Using Dirty)</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.inputName" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="12" ng-pattern="/^\w+$/" required>
    <div ng-messages="formValidation.username.$error" ng-show="formValidation.username.$dirty">
      <p ng-message="pattern">Username can only be alphanumeric with an optional underscore.</p>
      <p ng-message="maxlength">Username cannot be longer than 12 characters.</p>
      <div ng-messages-include="generic-messages"></div>
    </div>

    <label>Password (Using Touched)</label>
    <input type="text" name="userPassword" ng-model="user.inputPassword" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="12" required>
    <div ng-messages="formValidation.userPassword.$error" ng-show="formValidation.userPassword.$touched">
      <div ng-messages-include="generic-messages"></div>
    </div>

    <label>Email (Using Dirty)</label>
    <input type="email" name="userEmail" ng-model="user.inputEmail" required>
    <div ng-messages="formValidation.userEmail.$error" ng-show="formValidation.userEmail.$dirty">
      <p ng-message="required">This field is required.</p>
      <p ng-message="email">Please enter a valid email address.</p>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add custom validation to an AngularJS form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581439/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-an-angularjs-form)

Comment: No. I have to validate if the user clicks buttons and based on the button we have to validate objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate forms, in order to have the control of each one of them.

Create an array variable `$scope.forms = [];`, and use `$index` to set each form's name:

```
<form name="forms[{{$index}}]">
```

Now you can control each form using $index:

```
<button ng-click="myFunc($index)">check {{$index}}</button>
```

and use it to show errors or anything else:

```
$scope.myFunc = function(formIndex) {
    console.log(formIndex);
    console.log($scope.forms[formIndex]);
};
```

`$setSubmitted()` can be used also for different cases.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/df3owkzm/)
If you need further help please let me know

**EDIT**

When 'check all' is clicked, one approach would be to set all forms as submitted and show the field errors:

```
$scope.checkall = function(form) {
    $scope.forms[0].$setSubmitted();
    $scope.forms[1].$setSubmitted();
    console.log('form 1 is valid: ', $scope.forms[0].$valid);
    console.log('form 1 username field', $scope.forms[1].username);
    console.log('form 2 is valid: ', $scope.forms[1].$valid);
};
```

You can access each form like this (or with a loop over $scope.forms if you need a dynamic approach):

```
$scope.forms[0]
```

or a form field and its properties:

```
$scope.forms[1].username
```

in order to show the error message after the 'check all' button clicked, I changed the condition of each field like this:

```
ng-show="forms[$index].$submitted"
```

check the updated demo here: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vrLfg51c/10/)

Comment: if I click the check all button how can I get form information.

Comment: we have to dynamically check forms .here it's hardcoded.i think based on the index we can validate forms right?

Comment: why I'm not getting ng-message required validation. please check my demo if i remove value from a field you will get a message like This field is required.

Comment: You can use either `$submitted` or `$dirty`, here is the approach like yours, which shows the error after the input change [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u7da89he/)